# How do I run this program in the background

Tags: unix

mysql -u scott-h machine.domain.com -p -D foo_db < foo.sql

If I add an ampersand at the end, it suspends the job. I want the flexibility to run this background so that this time consuming process doesn't end, even if I log out of the shell / machine which launched it.

Should I be using nohup `enter code here`along with a `&` at the end. How do I know if this job got completed?

Comment: You will likely find the unix `screen` command useful for tasks like this. Type `man screen` on the command line for more info.

Comment: Why does it hang?  Because `mysql` reads from `/dev/tty` instead of standard input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `nohup` and `&` can be used.

i.e

```
nohup <your command line> >logfile 2>&1 &
```

For stderr and stdout to go to the logfile. Use /dev/null instead of logfile if you want not to record the output.

Answer (score 1):

you could run it as

```
prompt> mysql -u scott-h machine.domain.com -p -D foo_db < foo.sql &
prompt> bg
```